# MySQL procedure argument

Tags: mysql, procedure

I am having a strange problem with my database. I want to create a new procedure, but I am getting some errors and I don't know what is wrong. Can somebody help me? I am using phpMyAdmin

```
DELIMITER $$;
CREATE PROCEDURE liczSuma (IN newID INT)
BEGIN 
    SELECT encja.IDRezerwacja,SUM(encja.Suma)
        FROM (
        SELECT pokojpozycja.IDRezerwacja,SUM(pokoj.CenaPokoj) AS Suma
                    FROM `pokojpozycja` 
                    LEFT JOIN pokoj ON pokoj.IDPokoj = pokojpozycja.IDPokoj
                    GROUP BY  pokojpozycja.IDRezerwacja
                    WHERE  pokojpozycja.IDRezerwacja = newID ;
        UNION 
        SELECT uslugapozycja.IDRezerwacja , SUM(usluga.CenaUsluga) AS Suma
                    FROM `uslugapozycja` 
                    LEFT JOIN usluga ON usluga.IDUsluga = uslugapozycja.IDUsluga
                    GROUP BY (uslugapozycja.IDRezerwacja)
                    WHERE uslugapozycja.IDRezerwacja = newID 
                  )AS encja
                  GROUP BY (encja.IDRezerwacja)
END
DELIMITER $$;
```

Comment: What does that "strange problem" say?

Comment: procedure don`t see argument :/ #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE  pokojpozycja.IDRezerwacja = newID ;
        UNION

        SELECT uslugapozycja.ID' at line 11

Comment: Check where you use `;` ... and (re)move it from there ...

Comment: You have been provided an answer; if it's helpful, please vote it up. If it solved your problem, please mark it as accepted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of SQL syntax errors, including `GROUP BY` before `WHERE`, a spurious semicolon, and a missing delimiter after your query.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE liczSuma (IN newID INT)
BEGIN 
    SELECT encja.IDRezerwacja,SUM(encja.Suma)
    FROM (
        SELECT pokojpozycja.IDRezerwacja,SUM(pokoj.CenaPokoj) AS Suma
                    FROM `pokojpozycja` 
                    LEFT JOIN pokoj ON pokoj.IDPokoj = pokojpozycja.IDPokoj
                    WHERE  pokojpozycja.IDRezerwacja = newID
                    GROUP BY  pokojpozycja.IDRezerwacja
        UNION 
        SELECT uslugapozycja.IDRezerwacja , SUM(usluga.CenaUsluga) AS Suma
                    FROM `uslugapozycja` 
                    LEFT JOIN usluga ON usluga.IDUsluga = uslugapozycja.IDUsluga
                    WHERE uslugapozycja.IDRezerwacja = newID 
                    GROUP BY (uslugapozycja.IDRezerwacja)
    ) AS encja
    GROUP BY (encja.IDRezerwacja);
END
DELIMITER ;
```

(Pro tip: saying "I am getting some errors" is not helpful. Provide the errors.)